# can't get reference to the timer to cancle scheduleatfixedrate

Tags: java, timer

I am using java and android studio.  I am trying to close an activity I set up with a scheduleatfixedrate when I pause or destroy the app.  The problem is I cannot get the code to resolve the timer and tasknew reference I use to set up the scheduleatrfixedrate in the onpause and onDestroy methods.  Below is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    TimerTask tasknew = new readDevice();
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 1000, 500);
}

// Activity paused
@Override
protected void onPause() {                                                          
    super.onPause();
    tasknew.cancel();
    timer.purge();
}
```

Without being able to cancel the timer, it just keeps running in the background.

Update:

I solved the problem which I update my solution in case someone else new to java has this problem.  I found out all I had to do is move the statement creating tasknew and timer outside of onResume and moved the cancel and purge to the onDestroy method.  Below is my working code.

```
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity {
    private TimerTask tasknew = new readDevice();
    private Timer timer = new Timer();
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(tasknew, 1000, 500);
    }
 @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        tasknew.cancel();
        timer.purge();
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();                                                 
        mBluetoothGatt.close();                                                      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would have been enough to create a *daemon Timer*: 
`new Timer(true)`

So, the timer would end when the rest of non-daemon threads of the program end.